# Changing the input type of a field to text from passworfd in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I am new to Ext JS, i do have a password field and a **SHOW** button adjacent to it. Need to convert the masked password to text field when clicked on **SHOW**. Currently we just display the password in another pop up window when clicked on **SHOW**. How do i get the field **password** in order to change its **xtype** to **text** form **password**?

**Form.js**

```
{xtype: 'displayfield', value: 'Password&nbsp;', width: '16%', style: 'text-align: right', preventMark: 'true'},
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'password', 
                        inputType: 'password',
                        cls: 'textfield-with-border'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Show',
                        buttonAlign: 'left',
                        formBind: true,
                        handler: this.onShowPassword,
                        style: 'margin-left: 5px',
                        cls: '',
                        scope: this
                    },

onShowPassword : function(btn, ev) {
        var x = this.getForm().findField('password');
        x.xType = "text";
}
```

Previous onShowPassword() function is :

```
onShowPassword : function(btn, ev) {
        
        //encode form values into JSON data
        var jsonUpdate = Ext.util.JSON.encode(fields);
        
        //Encoding for the password for html to take it as a plain text
        var encodedPassword = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(fields.password);
                
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            scope: this,
            url: this.urlBase + 'xyz',
            headers: this.createTokenHeader(),
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: jsonUpdate,
            success: function(response){
                //decode JSON response
                var form = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert("info", "Password is: "+encodedPassword);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        Ext.Msg.hide();
                    },15000);
                            
            },
            failure: function(response){
                var error = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Some error occurred while showing the password, please try again after some time");
            }
        });     
    },
```

**Tried code:** (Did not work)

```
var x = this.getForm().findField('password');
var passwordFieldDom = x.getEl().dom;      
var typeAttribute = (passwordFieldDom.type === 'password'? 'text': password');
this.getForm().findField('password').getEl().dom.type === typeAttribute;
```

The above code does change the type from password to text but it does not reflect on the UI as non masked password, after this the password still comes in masked.

I need to make change in `onShowPassword()`. Let me know how can i do that.

Comment: Which toolkit are you using: classic or morder? Which versions of ExtJs?

Comment: I am using eclipse and the version is 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title: "Sample Form",
        padding: 5,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: "Password",
            name: 'password',
            value: "Some Password",
            inputType: 'password',
            cls: 'textfield-with-border'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Show',
            buttonAlign: 'left',
            formBind: true,
            handler: this.onShowPassword,
            style: 'margin-left: 5px',
            cls: '',
            scope: this,
            handler: function (btn, ev) {
                var passwordFieldDom = btn.previousSibling().getEl().dom;
                var typeAttribute = (passwordFieldDom.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password');
                passwordFieldDom.setAttribute('type', typeAttribute);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    passwordFieldDom.setAttribute('type', 'password');
                }, 2000); // 2 seconds
            }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/375r)

Comment: Thanks for the response Arthur. The 'Show' pop up used to open only for  15 secs earlier. After using the above handler, how can i keep that for 15 sec. I have updated the question above with the previous handler.

Comment: I tried with the code (updated in question), did not able to set the type as 'text' instead of password. The code suggested with getAttribute() did not work.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the working fiddle. Please, don't copy-paste the code without understanding, try to change it to the context of your code. Maybe it did not worked because of the scope, you are using "scope: this" which changes the scope of "Show" button handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was missing with the scope, correct.